# How to clear the editor from the search results but still keep view in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, search, ide

Right now Eclipse clears the editors highlights and from the view. Is it possible to clean the editor and still the results handy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations. In annotations types select **"Search results"** type. Deselect **"Vertical ruler"** and **"Text as"** check box.

Comment: What are Annotations in general?